# Can something worse than a temporary ban happen when I get too many rejected edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

If I try to edit multiple questions, and they all get rejected, could I potentially get a worse punishment than a temporary ban?

Comment: Define _something worse_ please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ C++ gets a script variant. That kind of worse ...

Comment: @rene It already got one: emscripten

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ where does this end ... horror ...

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the linked question because the answer there contains "account suspensions [...] are applied in severe cases of not improving after receiving automatic bans.", which is approximately what is said here.

Comment: @rene emscripten allowed us to get Blazor though, so it's not *all* bad.

Comment: Well ... i heard about few cases where it was requested from a user to do some coding for free ... using delphi ...in order to help out SO grow

Comment: @rene I do not see C++ scripts as horrors. They are, in fact, cool.

Comment: @SergeyA call me old fashioned and narrow minded

Comment: @SergeyA: You would then appreciate `#!/usr/bin/tcc -run`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In theory something worse can happen.

If you continue to get yourself into an automatic ban, the users and or moderators might start to notice.

When there is evidence that you don't improve or ignore advice presented to you by the system, you could risk a suspension handed out by a mod. Those start with days but can increase in length up to a year and if you persist on doing this network-wide be extended by community managers to 99999 days.

It would be a novum if you get a ~ 273 year suspension from just lousy edits.

Comment: Elected moderators only can ban up to a year. Longer bans are always network wide and can only be applied by the Community Managers. I have yet to see an upper limit to network bans; I’ve seen a 99999 day ban (~273 years and change) but the limit is more likely to be a database integer type limit. Network bans > 1 year are reserved for accounts that have shown to be completely unredeemable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I  described what I thought was already the worst that could happen ... you topped it. ;)

Comment: @Rene At least there's no threat of getting bludgeoned by a giant S...

Comment: 273 years makes me wonder if the site would last that much to insure this ban, I hope this comment sticks until 2292, so my grand grand grand child would answer this

Comment: The United States hasn't even existed for 273 years

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout Technically, SO doesn't need to exist _for_ 273 years. Just _in_ 273 years' time.

Comment: It would be more spectacular for someone to return from a 99999 day ban.

Comment: "Remember me??"

Comment: @Joshua "return from a 99999 day ban" Meanwhile in 2219: Sonny, I have something special for you today, I saved this for years, on this piece of paper I have something passed down from my dad, it's our family's original Stack Overflow username and password. You see your grandfather was trying to learn an ancient language called Python, but then he got tricked by a sales agency into promoting their products and they banned him. I'm passing this on to you because there's still hope, in 73 years you can fix this and bring pride back to the user2353482 family name!

Comment: And then the son says he prefers JavaScript.

Comment: "Sorry, Dad, but ECMAScript 2219 is all I know."

Comment: For a sec there I thought I wasn't on SO.

Comment: @holydragon welcome to Meta!

Comment: Being banned from here will only give you more time to do something else so ^_^

Comment: @Leaf ECMAScript 2019: `var site = document.generateEntireWebsiteAutomatically();`